# How do i apply effect when i add content using appendTo?

Tags: jquery

How do i apply effect when i add content using appendTo ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AddComment.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        comments: value1,
        sect1: value2,
        pid: value3,
        usid: value4

    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#txtHint").append(data);         
        $("#ta1").val('');      
    },
    error: function() {
        alert(data);
        return false;
    }
});
```

The above code is worked.But i want know how do add effect to the appended text.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to hide the content, add it to the DOM, and then show the content using an effect.

Using your code, change your success callback to the following:

```
success: function(data) {
    $data = $(data);
    $data.hide();
    $data.appendTo("#txtHint");
    $data.show("slow");
}
```

You can change the `.show("slow")` part to anything that will show content with an animation.